# How to add a keyword to a crawler callback function?

Tags: flask, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm having trouble to add a keyword to a crawler. I'm using `scrapy`, `flask` and `crochet`. The function is:

```
@crochet.run_in_reactor
def scrape_with_crochet(req):
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(Spider, output_data = output_data,**req)
    eventual.addCallback(finished_scrape,callbackKeywords = {'stash':5})
```

How can I add a keyword to `eventual.addCallback`. I have tried `eventual.addCallback(finished_scrape,callbackKeywords = {'stash':5})`

and `eventual.addCallback(finished_scrape,cb_kwargs= {'stash':5})`
but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the
[documentation](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#addCallback):

> `def addCallback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs): (source)`
> Convenience method for adding just a callback.
> Parameters
>
> - `callback` : `Callable`
>   `[...,Union[_NextDeferredResultT,Deferred[_NextDeferredResultT]]]`
> - `*args`: `object`
> - `**kwargs`: `object`

> Returns
>
> - `Deferred`
>   `[_NextDeferredResultT]`

Which means you would add it like this:

```
kwargs = {'stash': 5}

@crochet.run_in_reactor
def scrape_with_crochet(req):
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(Spider, output_data = output_data,**req)
    eventual.addCallback(finished_scrape, **kwargs)
```